# Changing image source results in empty image

Tags: javascript, html

I just figured out how to change an image's source with javascript and now it keeps setting the element to a blank image as if it can't find the file path even though when I control click on the path in visual studio it shows me the right image. Here's my code to change the image source:

```
setTimeout(function(){userImg.setAttribute('src', "‪file:///C:/Users/My%20Name/Desktop/websites/rockpaperscissors/images/paper.png")}, 300);
```

---

Running snippet

---

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  userImg.setAttribute('src', "‪https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/327-3278638_note-clipart-blank-paper-png-download.png")
}, 300);
```

```html
<title>
  Rock Paper Scissors Game
</title>
<header>
  <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
</header>
<div class="score-board">
  <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
  <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
  <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
</div>
<div class="result">
  <p>Make Your Move!</p>
</div>
<div class="choices">
  <div class="choice" id="r">
    <img src="images/rock.png" width="115" height="95">
  </div>
  <div class="choice" id="p">
    <img src="images/paper.png" width="120" height="120">
  </div>
  <div class="choice" id="s">
    <img src="images/scissors.png" width="130" height="110">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fighters">
  <div class="fighter" id="u">
    <img id="userimg" src="images/rock.png" width="370" height="300">
  </div>
  <div class="fighter" id="c">
    <img id="compimg" src="images/rockflipped.png" width="370" height="300">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="squares">
  <div class="square" id="userSquare"></div>
  <div class="square" id="computerSquare"></div>
</div>
<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? You should open the console view and check for errors.

Comment: Set the path relative to the HTML file when using local files.

Comment: Why are you setting it to a `file://` path?  Are you opening the website as a file, or as a website?  Check the browser's console for errors when you try to switch the image.

Comment: Yeah I honestly haven't been able to find anything about how to set a file path from my computer in javascript so I'm probably doing it wrong. I checked the console and it says file not found

Comment: JS Is CASE SENSITIVE. I made a snippet and added an existing image. Also you have all your body HTML in the HEAD. Use a relative path for your image and use `document.getElementById("userimg").src = "images/paper.png";`

Comment: If so, your file path is incorrect. You should double-check that the file exists or change the path to one relative to the .html file.

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Thanks mplungjan, that fixed the problem.

Comment: @Outflows Feel free to delete the question

Comment: Just a fun bit of info on another option. If you add this attribute to your image tag then it will function as a fallback image in the event that it cannot find your image or you encounter CORS issues: onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='' backupImageURLHere"  no js magic required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use **exact** file paths, especially if it's going to be hosted on a server eventually. What you'll want to do is serve your website from IIS, Apache, Nginx, Node.js, Xaamp, Wamp/Lamp/Mamp or some other web server so you can use a **relative** path like below:

```js
setTimeout(function(){userImg.setAttribute('src', "‪/images/paper.png")}, 300);
```

Where you `website.com` is being served at you can then use directories in the folder that holds it and sub folders like /images /js /css to get to your resources. So it'll look something like this:

```
|_ website root folder
   |_ index.html
   |_ images
      |_ yourimage.png
```

With relative paths you ahve better security and it's a standard practice. Whe nyou use an exact file path you can a host of issues from the local file system  to security concerns if you host the website. Also, exact paths won't be accessible outside of your computer, so you'll have to change it later on anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the browser doesn't attempt to get that image, you just took away the old one. Try replacing the whole image element.

```
function replaceImage (userImg) {
  let target = userImg.parentElement // where to place new element
  document.removeElement(userImg) // remove old element
  let newImage = document.createElement('img') //create new element
  newImage.setAttribute('src', 'C://filepath.jpg')
  newImage.setAttribute('id', 'userimg')
  target.appendChild(newImage) // place new element
}
```

The functions appendChild() and createElement() should alert the browser that it needs to get the new image from the new path.